# Building container image for AWS Lambda fails

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I want to deploy a container image with some Python libs and Python code which should be used as AWS lambda function. I followed the following blog post:
https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/machine-learning/using-container-images-to-run-pytorch-models-in-aws-lambda/

Locally on my machine I can build and run the Docker image successfully. From Docker perspective I thought this is ok. But when I use AWSSAMCLI, I get the following issue:

```
F:\AWS>sam build && sam deploy --guided
Your template contains a resource with logical ID "ServerlessRestApi", which is a reserved logical ID in AWS SAM. It could result in unexpected behaviors and is not recommended.
Building codeuri: F:\AWS runtime: None metadata: {'Dockerfile': 'Dockerfile', 'DockerContext': 'F:\\\AWS\\inference-ai'} architecture: x86_64 functions: InferenceFunction
Building image for InferenceFunction function
Setting DockerBuildArgs: {} for InferenceFunction function
Step 1/13 : FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
 ---> 7afff3a8d417
Step 2/13 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3e5e3aa3f81d
Step 3/13 : RUN yum install -y gcc git unzip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9ce3cda3d21a
Step 4/13 : RUN yum install -y python3-devel.x86_64
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ffcd1e85aa7d
Step 5/13 : RUN python3.9 -m pip install cython
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 178bccdc8433
Step 6/13 : RUN python3.9 -m pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 389d5f5d0a59
Step 7/13 : RUN python3.9 -m pip install git+https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git@cocodataset-master#subdirectory=PythonAPI
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6a1b0cc8c2c7
Step 8/13 : RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4111e9474c42
Step 9/13 : RUN curl https://gitlab.com/username/inference-ai/-/archive/main/inference-ai-main.zip --output project.zip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 580214e52eb2
Step 10/13 : RUN unzip project.zip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d49342aeca1
Step 11/13 : RUN mv inference-ai-main inference-ai
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c5ed0c584cbd
Step 12/13 : WORKDIR inference-ai
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 768f6092aa72
Step 13/13 : CMD ["test-infer-with-coco.lambda_handler"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d09be07424dd
Successfully built d09be07424dd
Successfully tagged inferencefunction:latest

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    cli(prog_name="sam")
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 166, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 124, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\utils\version_checker.py", line 41, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\cli\main.py", line 87, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\command.py", line 182, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\command.py", line 262, in do_cli
    ctx.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\build\build_context.py", line 255, in run
    modified_template = builder.update_template(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\build\app_builder.py", line 321, in update_template
    absolute_output_path = pathlib.Path(
  File "pathlib.py", line 1180, in resolve
  File "pathlib.py", line 205, in resolve
OSError: [WinError 123] Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch: 'inferencefunction:latest'

F:\AWS>
```

I have no idea why an invalid file will be used (colon character). How can I solve this issue?

#### Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN yum install -y gcc git unzip
RUN yum install -y python3-devel.x86_64
RUN python3.9 -m pip install cython
RUN python3.9 -m pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
RUN python3.9 -m pip install git+https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git@cocodataset-master#subdirectory=PythonAPI
RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN curl https://gitlab.com/username/inference-ai/-/archive/main/inference-ai-main.zip --output project.zip
RUN unzip project.zip
RUN mv inference-ai-main inference-ai
WORKDIR inference-ai
CMD ["test-infer-with-coco.lambda_handler"]
```

#### template.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 50
    MemorySize: 5000
  Api:
    BinaryMediaTypes:
      - image/png
      - image/jpg
      - image/jpeg

Resources:
  InferenceFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        Inference:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /inference-ai
            Method: post
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./inference-ai
      # DockerTag: python3.9-v1

Outputs:
  InferenceApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Inference function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/inference-ai/"
  InferenceFunction:
    Description: "Inference Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt InferenceFunction.Arn
  InferenceFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Inference function"
    Value: !GetAtt InferenceFunction.Arn
```

Comment: Sadly your issue is not reproducible. For example, you are using `COPY requirements.txt` yet the file is not provided.

Comment: @Marcin, oh, I thought the requirements.txt file is not that relevant for the creation of the container image. I will modify the example so that the unnecessary stuff is removed and the error reproducible.

Comment: I tried it on a recent Linux installation, and it worked without any modifications. Then I got an issue with WORKDIR, and moved all files up one level to /var/task, installed another library which is necessary for opencv (mesa-libgl), and then I got the lambda function up and running.